# CryEngine with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, cryengine

I receive an error in Visual Studio when I open CESharpFramework from my project folder. I had assumed I could use Visual Studio 2015; but the error tells me I need an older version of Visual Studio to open the MonoLauncher solution within CESharpFramework.

Is this a known issue and what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed GTK# and MonoDevelop.
I use CE5 with Visual Studio 2015 but not with C# but the docs said something about that.
I suggest you reffer to [this](http://docs.cryengine.com/display/CEPROG/CE%23+Framework) document, it should fix your issues.
Have you installed VS2015 with Xamarin support?

Comment: I actually referred to that document and installed GTK# and MonoDevelop. I did not install VS2015 with Xamarin support, though. Should that be necessary?

Comment: I think yes, cause you need the monodevelop/xamarin plugins